# Unable to get values form child to parent -Reactjs Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to update few values from child component to parent component.
but not all data are getting updated.

Let me know if there is any error......

Can anyone help me on this?

Parent component

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      invalidData: {},
      widgetsList: [],
      storyboardList: [],
      storyboardTitle: this.props.selectedBoard.boardTitle,
      isHidden: true,
      widgetCount: 0
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.storyboardList !== nextProps.storyboardList) {
      this.setState({ storyboardList: nextProps.storyboardList });
    }
  }

  addWidget = widgetType => {
    const newWidget = this.getNewWidget(widgetType);
    this.setState(
      {
        widgetsList: [...this.state.widgetsList, newWidget],
        isHidden: !this.state.isHidden,
        widgetCount: this.state.widgetCount + 1
      },
      () =>
        this.props.storyboardActions.addWidget(
          newWidget,
          this.props.selectedBoard.boardId
        )
    );
  };
  getNewWidget = widgetType => {
    if (this.props.storyboardList.length === 0) {
      console.log("stb", this.state.storyboardList.widgetList);
    }
    switch (widgetType) {
      case "venn":
        return {
          widgetName: `widget ${this.state.widgetCount}`,
          widgetType: "venn",
          leftTarget: "",
          rightTarget: "",
          leftTargetValue: 0,
          rightTargetValue: 0,
          position: { row: 0, col: 0 }
        };
      default:
        return {
          widgetName: `Default ${this.state.widgetCount}`,
          widgetType: "venn",
          leftTarget: "",
          rightTarget: ""
        };
    }
  };

  handleSaveButton = selectedBoardId => {
    const expressionsToSaveWidget = { ...this.getUserAccountRunParams() };
    console.log(this.props.storyboardList.boardList[selectedBoardId].spcxId);
    console.log(this.props.storyboardList.boardList[selectedBoardId]);
    this.props.storyboardList.boardList[selectedBoardId].spcxId === ""
      ? this.props.storyboardActions.newStoryboard(
          expressionsToSaveWidget,
          this.state.storyboardTitle,
          this.props.storyboardList.boardList[selectedBoardId]
        )
      : this.props.storyboardActions.updateStoryBoard(
          expressionsToSaveWidget,
          this.state.storyboardTitle,
          this.props.storyboardList.boardList[selectedBoardId]
        );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <VennDiagram
        boardId={this.props.selectedBoard.boardId}
        widgetDetail={widget}
        storyboardTargets={this.props.storyboardTargets}
        handleSaveButton={this.handleSaveButton}
        //handleWidgetChange={this.handleWidgetChange}
        handleRunWidget={this.handleRunWidget}
        handleDeleteWidget={this.handleDeleteWidget}
        handleDuplicateWidget={this.handleDuplicateWidget}
        handlechangeTarget={this.handlechangeTarget}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Child Component

```
class VennDiagram extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  currentDropdown: '',
  leftValue: 'A',
  rightValue: 'B',
  interSectionData: 'AB',
  };
  }
handelSelectionChange = baseData => {
  const Venndata = baseData.weighted;
  const venntext = baseData.keyword;
  console.log("widgetDetail", this.props.widgetDetail);
  let updatedWidget = {};
  const interSec =
    this.state.leftValue === "A" || this.state.leftValue === "B"
      ? "AB"
      : baseData.sample;
  if (this.state.currentDropdown === "left") {
    updatedWidget = {
      leftTarget: venntext,
      leftTargetValue: Venndata,
      widgetId: this.props.widgetDetail.widgetId,
      widgetName: this.props.widgetDetail.widgetName,
      widgetType: this.props.widgetDetail.widgetType
    };
    this.setState({
      leftValue: Venndata,
      interSectionData: interSec,
      lefttext: venntext
    });
    // this.props.handleWidgetChange(Venndata, 'left');
  } else {
    updatedWidget = {
      rightTarget: venntext,
      rightTargetValue: Venndata,
      widgetId: this.props.widgetDetail.widgetId,
      widgetName: this.props.widgetDetail.widgetName,
      widgetType: this.props.widgetDetail.widgetType
    };
    this.setState({
      rightValue: Venndata,
      interSectionData: interSec,
      righttext: venntext
    });
  }
  this.props.handleSaveButton(this.props.boardId);
  this.handleDropDownClose();
};
render() {
return (
  <div className="widget-wrapper">
    {this.props.storyboardTargets ? (
      <div className="target-base-dropdown" ref={node => (this.targetBaseDropdown = node)}>
        <h6>
          Select Target
          <button className="dropdown-close-button" onClick={this.handleDropDownClose}>
            <img src={clearIcon} alt="Close button" title="Close" />
          </button>
        </h6>
        <ul>
          {this.props.storyboardTargets &&
            this.props.storyboardTargets.map((base, index) => (
              <li key={index} value={base.keyword} onClick={() => this.handelSelectionChange(base)}>
                {base.originalTitle}
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    ) : (
      ''
    )}
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      version="1.1"
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width={415}
      height={240}
      style={{ fontSize: '15px' }}
    >
      <ellipse
        cx="150"
        cy="125"
        rx="100"
        ry="100"
        fill={this.state.leftValue === 'A' ? 'rgba(93, 86, 90, 0.3)' : this.props.leftBGColor}
        style={{ stroke: '#204454', strokeOpacity: '0.5' }}
      />
      <ellipse
        cx="275"
        cy="125"
        rx="100"
        ry="100"
        fill={this.state.rightValue === 'B' ? 'rgba(93, 86, 90, 0.3)' : this.props.rightBGColor}
        style={{ stroke: '#724f65', strokeOpacity: '0.5' }}
      />
      <text y="125" textAnchor="middle" id="1:77%">
        <tspan x="77%" dy="0" onClick={e => this.showDropdown(e, 'right')} className="right-value">
          {this.state.righttext} {this.state.rightValue}
        </tspan>
      </text>
      <text y="125" textAnchor="middle" id="2:23%">
        <tspan x="23%" dy="0" onClick={e => this.showDropdown(e, 'left')} className="left-value">
          {this.state.lefttext} {this.state.leftValue}
        </tspan>
      </text>
      <text y="125" textAnchor="middle" id="12:50%">
        <tspan x="50%" dy="0">
          {this.state.interSectionData}
        </tspan>
      </text>
    </svg>
    <p contentEditable="true" className="text-center">
      {this.props.widgetDetail.widgetName}
    </p>
    <Modal title="Add Target/Targets" ref={node => (this.addtarget = node)} dialogStyles={ModalAddTargetStyle}>
      <p>Please add target/targets to select.</p>
    </Modal>
  </div>
  );
  }
  }

 VennDiagram.defaultProps = {
 leftValue: 'A',
 leftBGColor: 'rgba(64, 137, 169, 0.3)',
 rightValue: 'B',
 rightBGColor: 'rgba(229, 159, 202, 0.3)',
 middleValue: '',
 widgetName: 'Widget 1',
 };
```

Need to update

```
    rightTarget: venntext,
    rightTargetValue: Venndata,
    leftTarget: venntext,
    leftTargetValue: Venndata,
```

Need to pass all the above 4 values to parent (BOARD component).
I am not able to update these above values. Can anyone help me on these? Please

Comment: What's the actual problem ? The question is too broad.

Comment: @DenysKotsur need to update four values to parent component

Answer (score 1):

You should keep these values in the parent component and pass them as props to child. Also, you need to pass function callback to child (updater).

The idea is:

**Board.js**

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rightTarget: '',
      rightTargetValue: '',
      leftTarget: '',
      leftTargetValue: '',
      // another part of state
    };
  }

  onValuesChange = values => {
      this.setState({ ...values })
  }

  render() {
      const { rightTarget, rightTargetValue, leftTarget, leftTargetValue } = this.state
      return (
          <VennDiagram 
                onValuesChange={this.onValuesChange}
                rightTarget={rightTarget}
                rightTargetValue={rightTargetValue}
                leftTarget={leftTarget}
                leftTarget={leftTargetValue}
          />
      )
  }
}
```

**VennDiagram.js**

```
class VennDiagram extends React.Component {
     ... all component's code above

     handelSelectionChange = baseData => {
          ... rest code 

          this.props.onValuesChange({ rightTarget: venntext,
                                      rightTargetValue: Venndata,
                                      leftTarget: venntext,
                                      leftTargetValue: Venndata, })
     }

     ... render etc
     // use all of these values (rightTarget, leftTarget, rightTargetValue, leftTargetValue) from `this.props` instead of `this.state`

}
```

Or just pass all of these values to your `handleSaveButton` callback.

```
// in child's component
this.props.handleSaveButton(this.props.boardId, { rightTarget: venntext,
                                          rightTargetValue: Venndata,
                                          leftTarget: venntext,
                                          leftTargetValue: Venndata, })

// in parent
handleSaveButton = (selectedBoardId, values) => {
    ... rest of the code
    this.setState({...values})
}
```

Comment: When save button is clicked handleSaveButton  will be called ....storyboardlist.boardlist consists of array of objects

Comment: I've updated answer. If you don't need to use these values anywhere else, you can just store it in state and pass as props to child and use inside the parent component. In `handleSaveButton` pass it to parent and call `setState`. You can use them in `getNewWidget` method afterwards.

Comment: when ever i update bothe right and left value will be same.still when i click save button values will be undefined

Comment: this.props.storyboardList.boardList all the values will be inside this only

Comment: this is the format of storyboardlist  in this i need to update those 4 values             
 storyboard: {
    boardList: [
      {
        boardId: '1456',
        boardTitle: 'Board1',
        createdAt: 1526896964626,
        modifiedAt: 1526896980257,
        spcxId: '',
        widgetList: [
          {
            widgetId: '',
            widgetName: 'Venn',
            widgetType: 'venn',
            leftTarget: '',
            rightTarget: '',
            leftTargetValue: 0,
            rightTargetValue: 0
          },